deltalake scala api for unit-testing
I was able to make deltalake work locally for unit-testing data+spark app logic.
      def readDeltaLake(path: String)(implicit sc: SparkSession): DataFrame =
        sc.read
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource")
          .load(path)


    // local spark session
    implicit val sparkSession: SparkSession = aSparkSession() 
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    // path to scala/test/resources with parquet file
    io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.convertToDelta(sparkSession, s"parquet.`${singleInput.getParent.toFile.getAbsolutePath}`") 

    val myTestData = readDeltaLake(singleInput.getParent.toFile.getAbsolutePath)
    myTestData.count() shouldBe 42L

Code above works fine, but I want to mimic real delta lake layout with partitions.
My partition schema is:
hdfs://my_data/delta/ds=2024-05-27 23%3A00%3A00

how can I create same thing but with date partitions?

what did you try to use with partitionBy, write and that format that failed?

didn't fully understand your question...

you've not shown anything that you've tried, so it's difficult to know where you failed.  Normally to save a dataframe you specify format when writing out (write.format.save), which would typically work here (just as your read.format.load did).  https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#overwrite and the scala tab shows this

Code above works well, it converts test parquet file into DeltaLake format. I need to mimic partition schema and save file as partitioned DeltaLake table.

understood, but have you tried what the link I sent shows?

awesome, I've added that as an answer for others to more easily find

Per the comments and the link writing delta:
val data = spark.range(5, 10)
data.partitionBy("","").write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/delta-table")
df.show()

